# Socket HTTP request returning invalid GZIP

Tags: java, sockets, http, gzip

I am teaching myself more about HTTP requests and such, so I wrote a simple POST request using Java's HttpURLConnection class and it returns compressed data which is easily decompress. I decided to go a lower level and send the HTTP request with sockets (for practice). I figured it out after a series of google searches, but there is one issue. When the server respondes with compressed data it isn't valid. Here is an image of a bit of debugging.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rECIT.png

The portion below the "=" separator line is the response when using a HttpURLConnection instance, but the portion above it is the response when using sockets. I'm not too sure what is going on here. The bottom part is valid, while the top is not.

The HttpParameter and header classes simply store a key and value.

```
public String sendPost(String host, String path, List<HttpParameter> parameters, List<HttpHeader> headers) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    String data = this.encodeParameters(parameters);
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, 80);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    writer.println("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1");
    for(HttpHeader header : headers) {
        writer.println(header.getField() + ": " + header.getValue());
    }
    writer.println();
    writer.println(data);
    writer.flush();
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        contentBuilder.append(line + "\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    return contentBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Readers and/or Writers by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, this is how I am getting the content. http://pastebin.com/rY7DQfKv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `Reader`s and `Writer`s for something that is not text.

`InputStream` and `OutputStream` work with bytes; `Reader` and `Writer` work with encoded text. If you try to use `Reader` and `Writer` with something that is not encoded text, you will mangle it.

Sending the request with a Writer is fine.

You want to do something like this instead:

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

// ...

ByteArrayOutputStream contentBuilder = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768]; // the size of this doesn't matter too much
int num_read;
while(true) {
    num_read = in.read(buffer);
    if(num_read < 0)
        break;
    contentBuilder.write(buffer, 0, num_read);
}
in.close();
writer.close();
return contentBuilder.toByteArray();
```

and make `sendPost` return a byte array.